# Check if required fields are filled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem. I want to run a function but it can only be run when I'm 100% sure the required fields are filled.

ATM it just executes the function even tho the required fields are not filled.

```
<input id="ticket-title" uib-tooltip="Insert a title for the ticket" 
       class="ticket-title" name="title" type="text"
       placeholder="Write a title for the ticket" ng-model="vm.ticket.TITLE" required>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default p1" ng-click="vm.createTicket()">
    Submit <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
</button>
```

Controller

```
vm.createTicket = function () {
    // I need a way to check if the form/fields are filled.
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [See if this topic helps you =)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215843/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-campos-preenchidos-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio)

Comment: Look into [`Angular Validation`](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp) which a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Give your input a model like:

```
<input id="ticket-title" ng-model="ticket" placeholder="Insert ticket title"/>
```

and in your JS do this:

```
if ($scope.ticket!= null && $scope.ticket!= "") {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input id="ticket-title" uib-tooltip="Insert a title for the ticket" 
   class="ticket-title" name="title" type="text"
   placeholder="Write a title for the ticket" ng-model="vm.ticket.TITLE" 
   required>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default p1" 
    ng-disabled="vm.disableTicket()" ng-click="vm.createTicket()">
   Submit <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
   </button>


  Controller :
 vm.disableTicket = function() {
   return !vm.ticket.TITLE;
 }
```